# Status of Positional Tracker Unity/Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am using Vuforia in Unity. I use Positional Tracker (Device Tracker) and I need to know the status of tracker/image_target.

Like "Trackable image_1  found" or "Trackable  image_1 lost".

I have to use Positional Tracker (Device Tracker).

The question is "How can I get the status of Positional Tracker?" I need to use multiple image recognition and I need to know the status of the image targets.

Comment: So what is the question? StackOverflow is no `Please make my homework` page. Please refer to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back with a specific programming related issue.

Comment: Hi. The question is "How can I get the status of Positional Tracker?"
I need to use multiple image recognition and I need to know status of image targets